# How can i send mail to multiple addresses but grouped by 20-30 to avoid spamming in php?

Tags: php

I want to bulk mails avoiding spam in php but I still do know how.

I have this function that returns the email addresses

```
public function getEmailAddress(){
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT email,login FROM account.account";
        $stmt=$this->o_db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }
```

This function for send email:

```
public function sendVoucherCode($array2,$voucher){ 
        $list = "";
        foreach($array2 as $recipient){
            if($recipient['email'] != NULL){
               $list .= $recipient['email'].','; 
            }
        }
        $email_array = explode(",",$list);
        foreach($email_array as $email)
        {
            $mail_own='Staff@blabla.ro';
            $subject = 'Voucher cadou ';
            $msg = '<html><body>';
            $msg .= 'Ai primit un cod promotional care valoareaza <font color="darkorange">'.$value.'</font> monede.  ' ."<br>";
            $msg .= 'Adaugă codul: <b>'.$voucher.'</b> în meniul validare voucher pentru a primii monedele!'."<br>";
            $msg .= 'Ține mine ofertă valabilă de la <b>'.$current_date.'</b> până la <b>'.$day_exp."</b><br>";
            $msg .= "<br>"."<br>";
            $msg .= 'Acest email este generat automat. Vă rugăm să nu răspundeți!'."<br>";
            $msg .= "WebMaster -> Alex";
            $msg .= '</body></html>';
            $headers = "From: $mail_own\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
            $success = mail($email,$subject,$msg,$headers);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And so i call them:

```
$array2 = $this->getUserFunctions()->getEmailAddress();
$this->getUserFunctions()->sendVoucherCode($array2,$voucher);
```

How is possible to send emails grouped by 20-30 but in the end send to all? Or is there another way?

EDIT : i was blocked on ip when i sent to 100 addresses

Comment: Nowadays to prevent your e-mail to be treated as spam u'd need to configure [SPF, DKIM, DMARC, ..](https://serverfault.com/questions/523443/spf-vs-dkim-the-exact-use-cases-and-differences)

Comment: And more info on this topic over [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam)

Comment: @DarkBee ok, but i don't know how to set this .. i have a web host , with a share cpanel.. and i want to send once time or how many i need (but verry few times) mails to all database with a promotional code.

Comment: You could start a free [mailchip](https://mailchimp.com/pricing/) account to solve your problems - sending mails from `localhost` is a real pita now, especially when you're not using any library like `phpmailer` or `swiftmailer` to take care of things

Answer (score 1):

Chunk your array of addresses. Take a look at [array_chunk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). The [mail](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function allows multiple addresses in the `$to` argument.

So:

```
$addresses = array_chunk($list, 20);
foreach( $addresses as $group ){
    ...
    mail(implode(',', $group), $subject, ...
```

Comment: Yeah i read now, but i forgot to say to send emails at a time in 5 minutes for exemple. I come back after

Comment: haha. Well if you leave out an important part of the question, can you blame me for not giving you the best solution? ;)

Comment: No , but if you send in pieces or all without time, it is not considered spam ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table and store a sent emails history (a column containing the user id and another one containing the time email was sent). Then inside your PHP script do a "for loop" with 20-30 iterations to send emails to users not found in your new table (email history). You should then use a cron job to run your script at certain intervals (30mins or 1h).

Answer (score 0):

In below code we are chunking the array in 20-20 value and then creating them as a one string with "," in this way every loop will send email to 20 emails.
Note:
Please change variable name accordingly.

```
public function sendVoucherCode($array2,$voucher){ 
    $list = "";
    foreach($array2 as $recipient){
        if($recipient['email'] != NULL){
           $list .= $recipient['email'].','; 
        }
    }
    $email_array = explode(",",$list);
    $GroupingEmail = array_chunk($email_array,20);//Add this line
    foreach($GroupingEmail as $email)
    {
        $sendEmailTo = impload(',',$email);//Add this line
        $mail_own='Staff@blabla.ro';
        $subject = 'Voucher cadou ';
        $msg = '<html><body>';
        $msg .= 'Ai primit un cod promotional care valoareaza <font color="darkorange">'.$value.'</font> monede.  ' ."<br>";
        $msg .= 'Adaugă codul: <b>'.$voucher.'</b> în meniul validare voucher pentru a primii monedele!'."<br>";
        $msg .= 'Ține mine ofertă valabilă de la <b>'.$current_date.'</b> până la <b>'.$day_exp."</b><br>";
        $msg .= "<br>"."<br>";
        $msg .= 'Acest email este generat automat. Vă rugăm să nu răspundeți!'."<br>";
        $msg .= "WebMaster -> Alex";
        $msg .= '</body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $mail_own\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
        $success = mail($sendEmailTo,$subject,$msg,$headers);//change this line
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok but if i send grouped mail but the time does not differ is not considered spam ? It's not the same thing as sending them all at once?

Comment: Do you think, sending mail to many people at once create spam email ? try to send to a single person and check if it is in spam or not. spam depend on many point. most importantly spam is due to content in html.

Comment: I already check it, if i send to one,two,three it's ok but, if i send to all database i was blocked ..

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the PEAR:MAIL.
Several hundred emails are perfectly sent, but free access to smtp (without authorization) is needed:

```
function send_email($to, $from, $subject, $body) {
    require_once "Mail.php";
    require_once "Mail/mime.php";    
    $host = "your.smtp.server.com";

    $headers['From'] = $from;
    $headers["Reply-To"] = $from;
    $headers["Return-path"] = $from;
    $headers['To'] = $to;
    $headers['MIME-Version'] = '1.0';
    $headers['X-Mailer'] = 'MUA name';
    $headers['Subject'] = $subject;

    $mime_params = array(
        'text_encoding' => '7bit',
        'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $mime = new Mail_mime();
    $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true; 
    }
};
```

Forming a http-body email and get status as json.
If you want to send all the letters at once by the package you need to call this code in a circle, but remember that most smtp servers have a limit on the simultaneous number of recipients and the number of letters sent per unit of time.

```
// form mail header
$to = $recipient_address;
$from = "address@company.com";
$subject = "My subject";
// form mail body
$message = "<html><head><title>MyTitle</title></head><body>";
$message .= "<p>Text1</p>";
$message .= "<p>Text2</p>";
$message .= "</body></html>\r\n";
// send mail
if ( send_email($to, $from, $subject, $message) ) {
    echo '{ "success": true, "msg": "OK" }';
} else {
    echo '{ "success": false, "msg": "We have a problem" }';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can try BCC model, then you can send to many people once time.
When send mail, we can set to (receiver), cc (everyone can know cc users), bcc (protected), and them both allow more than one address there, like mail-1; mail-2...